# Laravel export excel error in php 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-excel

I have implemented https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel in my project everything is working fine in dev mode with php 5.6.4

But when moved to production server with php 7 i'm getting the following error

```
This site can’t be reached

The webpage at http://35.154.248.39/download_excel might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
```

Looking forward for much needed help

thank you

Comment: check this link https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1112

Comment: Not sure about modules but same modules are enabled in PHP7 as per 5.6? Mostly Zip Extension.

Comment: @Dhaval Chheda thank you that helped me